# Step Image fading between two image paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, blending

I'm using Inkscape.

How would I do image fading, say about 5 steps equally spaced, so that they eventually blend into the background.

[image]

So I want to go black to red (the second black figure to the upper right would not end up black, this is just a diagram).

Basically I'm trying to do something the same as this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQfJMQyc4Fg
but with images not letters.

The images are already paths.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have your tried *Extensions > Generate from Path > Interpolate*? - [see screenshot](https://imgur.com/YsIt7ex)

Comment: Thanks very much - I will take a look

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the fill of one shape to red, the other black.
2. Make sure you send the red shape to the bottom of the stack - you can use <kbd>End</kbd> or *Object > Lower to bottom*
3. Select both shapes
4. Do *Extensions > Generate from Path > Interpolate* - see settings below. Engage the preview, and click Apply when you are happy with the result

[image]Click to enlarge